# AWS Glue Schedule a Job with Cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-glue

I would like to ask how can I schedule a AWS Glue job from AWS cli or boto3.

I couldn't find it in the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-job.html) either boto3 [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_job)

[image]

I know there is another way that includes creating a Trigger linked to the job, but not I'm not sure which it's the recommended one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best (subjective) and the only way I'm aware of and that's documented by AWS is to do it by creating a JSON file first, for example:

```json
{
  "Name": "your_schedule",
  "Description": "AWS GLUE docs suck",
  "Schedule": "cron(0 12 * * ? *)",
  "Actions": [
    {
      "JobName": "test_job"
    }
  ]
}
```

and then supply it as an argument to the `aws glue`, like this:

```
aws glue create-trigger --type SCHEDULED --cli-input-json file://your_job_schedule.json
```

If you got all the bits right, the output should be like this:

```
{
    "Name": "your_schedule"
}
```

Full syntax for the JSON file is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_CreateTrigger.html).

The docs you need are:

- [create trigger](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/create-trigger.html)
- [update trigger](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/update-trigger.html)
- [delete trigger](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/delete-trigger.html)

Comment: You are right, that's the way I found as well, just was wondering how can I activate the Schedules but couldn't. Thank you!

I like the easter egg in the description.